# How to reenable jQuery in Joomla 3

Tags: jquery, joomla

I was trying to enable jQuery in my Joomla 3 site. I pasted php code suggested here in my index.php and even in Gantry 5 head properties.

Now it looks like jQuery is disabled as I get the following in Chrome log:

```
jquery.magnific-popup.min.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: a is not a function
    at jquery.magnific-popup.min.js:4
    at jquery.magnific-popup.min.js:4
    at jquery.magnific-popup.min.js:4
(anonymous) @ jquery.magnific-popup.min.js:4
(anonymous) @ jquery.magnific-popup.min.js:4
(anonymous) @ jquery.magnific-popup.min.js:4
k2.frontend.js?v=2.8.0&sitepath=/:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at k2.frontend.js?v=2.8.0&sitepath=/:1
(anonymous) @ k2.frontend.js?v=2.8.0&sitepath=/:1
jquery-migrate.min.js?c853c2828819295af6a797b67db0bb65:2 JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1
```

Please help!

Comment: you could just add `<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>` in head and jquery would be enabled in your site

Comment: @M0ns1f I am totally new in web development. Where exactly do I put this code?

Comment: Anyway I think it has some thing to do with noConflict.
I just want to revert back to its normal behavior where I didn't have to load jQuery manually.
Suggestions please!